# Find the roots of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I am trying to find the below roots of the polynomial -

$x^4 - x^3 + x^2 -x + 1 = 0$

Below is what I tried -

=$x^3 (x -1) + x (x - 1) + 1 = 0$

=$(x^3-1)(x+1)=-1$

Am I approaching the right way? But I am unable to proceed after this - how can I solve this - will this equation result in complex roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $t=x+1/x$ and divide given equation with $x^2$, so:

$$ x^2-x+1-1/x+1/x^2=0 \implies t^2-t-1=0$$

so $$t_{1,2} = {1\pm \sqrt{5}\over 2}$$

**1.case**  $$x+{1\over x} = {1+ \sqrt{5}\over 2}\implies 2x^2-x(1+\sqrt{5})+2=0$$
$$ x_{1,2} = {1+\sqrt{5}\pm i\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\over 2}$$

**2.case**  $$x+{1\over x} = {1- \sqrt{5}\over 2}\implies 2x^2-x(1-\sqrt{5})+2=0$$
$$ x_{3,4} = {1-\sqrt{5}\pm i\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}+10}\over 2}$$

Comment: Thanks - but is there a generic way to know or assume what the value of t should be? How can we determine its value for a given equation?

Comment: As far as I know it is a trick that works occasionally, say when we have symmetric polynomial of even degree. There is no general aproach for $t$.

Comment: How many number of roots and what are the roots of unity here?

Comment: They are all, but they are not writen in trigonmetric way

Comment: Your first equation looks like $\phi$. How is that involved?

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $p(-x) = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = \frac{x^5-1}{x-1} $ for any $x \neq 1$.

So $p(x) = \frac{x^5+1}{x+1} $, thus its roots are the primitive $10-$roots of unity.

Comment: I was going to say multiply through by $x+1$ which gives $x^5+1$ - equivalent to your approach, but yours is nicely observed.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=\Phi_{10}(x) $$
hence the roots of the LHS are the primitive tenth roots of unity, $\exp\left(\frac{\pi k i}{5}\right)$ for $k\in\{1,3,7,9\}$.
They can be found through $\cos\frac{\pi}{5}=\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt{5})$ and $\sin\frac{\pi}{5}=\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8}}$.

Comment: as per the above step the value of k is supposed to be 0,1,2,3,4
but can please define how the value of k landed on 1,3,7,9

Comment: @Programmer: the *primitive* tenth roots of unity (i.e. the roots of the tenth cyclotomic polynomial) are $\omega,\omega^3,\omega^7,\omega^9$ with $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{10}$ since $\{1,3,7,9\}$ are the only elements of $[1,10]$ coprime with $10$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Dear Teacher, is it possible look at the Michael Rozenberg's answer? Thank you.         
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2910706/460962

Comment: @Math: Micheal is right, such expression is unbounded for $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$. It is also completely unrelated to the actual question/answer.

Comment: Thank you very much..But Wolfram Alpha says me $\sqrt[3]{1-4x}=- \sqrt [3]{4x-1}$ an equality appears is only at the point $ x=\frac 14$

Comment: @Math: that happens because Mathematica deals with $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ as a multi-valued function, which is not consistent with the usual definition of $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ as a real-valued function. Indeed such question heavily relies on the *definition* of $\sqrt[3]{a}$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}^-$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thank you Master. I think I need a good lesson to understand this subject..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: One solution is given by $$x=1/4\sqrt {5}+1/4+i/4\sqrt {2}\sqrt {5-\sqrt {5}}$$

Comment: Thanks but how to arrive at this step?

Comment: Searche for solving the quartic

Answer (score 0):

Here you can actually use a result from convolution. If we multiply the polynomial with $x+1$ we see we get $$x^5+1 = 0$$

This polynomial has the famous "*roots of unity*" which are complex numbers on the unit circle. So the roots to the equation are all $4$ roots with equal spacing except for the $x=-1$ one.